# Azure Policy to check VM Size is set to the value of tag 'ProductionSize' on the VM resource

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

Does anyone know if it is possible, to have an Azure Policy, that checks that the VM size is set to the same value as the value of Tag 'ProductionSize' which is on the same VM Resource?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check that the VM size equals the tag value. You should use the Modify effect for tags which will allow you to add or replace. I would model it after one of the inherit built-in policies.